# How to manage many pictures both on pc as on external hard drives?

Tags: photo-management

I'm using Darktable to edit and rate my pictures.
However at some point the folders need to be moved to an external HDD.
How do you manage that?

It would be great to be able to search for tags (maybe thumbnails) of the pictures located externally.